# ScrollView not Working in my relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I followed someone example on having a relative layout with a scrollview. I did exactly it and my page still won't scroll. Am I missing out something? Or must I change it to a linear layout to make it work? Still new to Android Studio here. 
Any help will be much appreciated. Randomly adding words so I can post this.

### activity_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="900dp"



tools:context="mapp.com.sg.receiptscanner.Info">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="900dp"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="900dp"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:text="Name of Product:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Company:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="61dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="61dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
            android:text="Receipt Number:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:text="Start Date of Warranty:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />




<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="273dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText10"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText10"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="Expiry Date of Warranty:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText11"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Bought from:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText10"
    android:layout_marginTop="177dp"
    android:text="Warranty Site:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
     </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can able to scroll the view only when the items in the scroll view exits the visibility. I check your code it happens for your layout too. For checking add few more item in that scroll view, It will start scroll

And one more thing instead of setting some constant value set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mapp.com.sg.receiptscanner.Info">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 0):

always use this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

for scrollview and its only child.